# Reload function after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a plugin raty (http://wbotelhos.com/raty) that is loaded to document.ready, the page content changes at the click of a button reloading a part of the DOM, and the document is not ready "recalculated" and I will not reload all javascript (there are other similar behavior) I tried this solution but without success

```
function star(){
alert("star");
...code plugin...
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    star();
});

$.ajax({
        ..code.. 
        done: function(creaStella) {
            alert("D");
            star();
        },
        complete:function(){
            alert("C");
star();
        },

    });
```

After call ajax i have alert("star") but i haven't my div populated

Comment: This is just an assertion. What is the question???

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect usage of $.ajax

```
 $.ajax({
    ..code..
    success: function(creaStella) {  
         //code to populate div goes here
        alert("complete");
        star();
    }
}).done(function(){
    //or here
   alert("complete2");
 });
```

use success/done as show (or both).

Comment: dosen't see my plugin because i have to do this in my star():

$('#star').raty();

where in my DOM
<div id="star"></div>

Comment: so do you pass some parameters like `{ score: 3 }`?

Comment: if i do $('#star').raty(); in chrome console i see my plugin

Answer (score 0):

I resolve in this Way..(promise().done)
also form with jquery validate plugin before dosen't works

```
function star(){
    //plugin star    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    formJqueryValidate1();
    formJqueryValidate2();
    star();
});


function formJqueryValidate1() {
    //my check

function formJqueryValidate2() {
    //my check
}


$.ajax({

    success: function(msg) {
        $('#myid').html(msg.template).promise().done(function(){
            formJqueryValidate1();
            formJqueryValidate2();
            star();
        });
    }

}

});
```